# Return Sheets data based on URL Parameter in Google Apps Script / Web App

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications, url-parameters

This is a piece of a larger project. Essentially, I'm going to have a link with a parameter ("formid" in this case) that I need to use to retrieve the correct row number from a Google sheets table. The code below works the way I want it to with the exception of the parameters not being used and the rows being retrieved are hard coded. I'd like to change this so the getBody row corresponds to formid number (ie.: if formid=4 then the 4th row would be displayed. Column positions can be hardcoded, I only need the one variable to be used.

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<form>
  <h1><center>Sheet</center></h1>
</form>
<script>
  google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
    document.getElementById("formid").value = location.parameters.formid[0];
  });
</script>



<div>
        <table>
      <thead>
        <? const headers = getHeaders();
        for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) { ?>
          <tr>
            <? for (let j = 0; j < headers[0].length; j++) { ?>
            <th><?= headers[i][j] ?></th>
            <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
      </thead>      
   <tbody>
      <? const body = getBody(); 
      for (let k = 0; k < body.length; k++) { ?>
        <tr>
          <? for (let l = 0; l < body[0].length; l++) { ?>
          <td><?= body[k][l] ?></td>
          <? } ?>
      <? } ?>     
    </tbody> 
    </table>
    </div>




</body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```js
function doGet() {
return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
        .evaluate();      
          }



function getHeaders() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NnG5lEKowlU6i2ZzkyCD1bjFtFGcgaODKZxvG179XfM/"; 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    return sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
}

function getBody() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NnG5lEKowlU6i2ZzkyCD1bjFtFGcgaODKZxvG179XfM/"; 
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const firstRow = 8;
  const numRows =  1;
  return sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
}
```

I've reviewed many related questions but either the solutions didn't seem to work or it wasn't clear what the full solution was. Perhaps I missed something.

I've tried inserting "formid" into the "return sheet.getRange()" but I keep getting an error that formid isn't an int.

I've made several attempts at this and the code above represents the closest and simplest script that has gotten me most of the way there.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'd like to change this so the getBody row corresponds to formid number (ie.: if formid=4 then the 4th row would be displayed. Column positions can be hardcoded, I only need the one variable to be used.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the help.
If I have a URL like this:
https://script.google.com/home/projects/SCRIPTIDHERE/dev?formid=5
I would want to display data on the page from row # 5 on the spreadsheet
The goal is to return data from only the row specified in the parameter. 
I hope that helps, let me know if I can clarify further

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help. I need to pass the parameter in the url ("5" in my previous comment) to the get.Range function as the row number.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to control the values using the query parameter of `formid=5`. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, when `formid=5` is used, you want to retrieve only row 5?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for, thank you very much. I do have one question, is there a way to set which columns are returned as well? This could be set in the code, not in a parameter

Comment: Right now the code you suggested below returns the entire row. What if I wanted to only return the 3rd column?

Comment: About your new question of `Right now the code you suggested below returns the entire row. What if I wanted to only return the 3rd column?`, in this case, please modify my sample script as follows. ``const h = `<thead><tr><th>${header[2]}</th></tr></thead>`; const b = `<tbody><tr><td>${values[formid - 1][2]}</td></tr></tbody>`;``

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I needed. I greatly appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to show only a row from the Spreadsheet by giving the row number using the query parameter like `formid=5`.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, it seems that you are retrieving the query parameter on the HTML side. In this case, when the template is used, after the HTML is loaded, `google.script.url.getLocation` is run. So, in this answer, I would like to propose retrieving the query parameter on the Google Apps Script side.
- In the current stage, when the loop process is included in the HTML template, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f1436d88423077115d2c249862f12f17)

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### HTML side:

In your HTML, `document.getElementById("formid")` is not found. So, in this modification, only HTML template without the script is used.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1>
      <center>Sheet</center>
    </h1>
  </form>
  <div>
    <table>
      <?!= table ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

In this modification, only `doGet` function is used as follows.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NnG5lEKowlU6i2ZzkyCD1bjFtFGcgaODKZxvG179XfM/";

  const { formid } = e.parameter;
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const [header, ...values] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const h = "<thead><tr>" + header.map(e => `<th>${e}</th>`).join("") + "</tr></thead>";
  const b = values[formid - 1] ? "<tbody><tr>" + values[formid - 1].map(e => `<td>${e}</td>`).join("") + "</tr></tbody>" : "";
  const html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('i16');
  html.table = h + b;
  return html.evaluate();
}
```

- In this modification, for example, when a Web Apps URL like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev?formid=5` including the query parameter is used, `formid=5` is retrieved in the `doGet` function, and only the row of `formid=5` is shown.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: This does exactly what I asked for, thank you very much. I do have one question, is there a way to set which columns are returned as well? This could be set in the code, not in a parameter

Comment: @Stuart `This does exactly what I asked for, thank you very much.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Stuart About your new question of `I do have one question, is there a way to set which columns are returned as well? This could be set in the code, not in a parameter`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. Can I ask you the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.